# Javascript Regex to get text between certain characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex in Javascript that would allow me to match an order number in two different formats of order URL:

The URLs:

```
http://store.apple.com/vieworder/1003123464/test@test.com

http://store.apple.com/vieworder/W411234368/test@test.com/AOS-A=
M-104121
```

The first one will always be **all numbers**, and the second one will always **start with a W, followed by just numbers**.

I need to be able to use a single regex to return these matches:

```
1003123464
W411234368
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
/(vieworder\/)(.*?)(?=\/)/g
```

[RegExr link](http://regexr.com/3b5hb)

That allows me to match:

```
vieworder/1003123464
vieworder/W411234368
```

but I'd like it to *not* include the first capture group.

I know I could then run the result through a `string.replace('vieworder/')`, but it'd be cool to be able to do this in just one command.

Comment: If none of the answers worked or you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your expression without *grouping* `vieworder`

```
vieworder\/(.*?)(?=\/)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eU9sL9/1)

```js
var string = 'http://store.apple.com/vieworder/1003123464/test@test.com http://store.apple.com/vieworder/W411234368/test@test.com/AOS-A=M-104121';
var myRegEx = /vieworder\/(.*?)(?=\/)/g;

var index = 1; 
  var matches = [];
  var match;
  while (match = myRegEx.exec(string)) {
    matches.push(match[index]);
  }
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: this will result `vieworder` also.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, no it doesnt. It is highlighted but not inluded in the match itself

Comment: it displays in the output of match function. You need to use exec function to get all the chars from group index 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace` instead of match since js won't support lookbehinds. You could use capturing groups and `exec` method to print the chars present inside a particular group.

```
> var s1 = 'http://store.apple.com/vieworder/1003123464/test@test.com'
undefined
> var s2 = 'http://store.apple.com/vieworder/W411234368/test@test.com/AOS-A='
undefined
> s1.replace(/^.*?vieworder\/|\/.*/g, '')
'1003123464'
> s2.replace(/^.*?vieworder\/|\/.*/g, '')
'W411234368'
```

**OR**

```
> s1.replace(/^.*?\bvieworder\/([^\/]*)\/.*/g, '$1')
'1003123464'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest

```
W?\d+
```

That ought to translate to "one or zero W and one or more digits".